# CAKEPHP - panel view form

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp

Can you combine javascript panels to split up a form in Cakephp with the Form Helper? I'm just starting out with cake php and find it hard to find my way around it... yes I did RTM...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can. The helper only writes form and form input HTML tags for you; if you know how to do it manually you know how to do it with `FormHelper`.

Comment: I tried and it's working although the post won't work yet but that'll be just me probably. thanks anyway